# Assign to an array and replace emerged nil values

Tags: ruby, arrays, null

Greetings!

When assigning a value to an array as in the following, how could I replace the `nil`s by `0`?

```
array = [1,2,3]
array[10] = 2
array # => [1, 2, 3, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 2]
```

If not possible when assigning, how would I do it the best way afterwards? I thought of `array.map { |e| e.nil? ? 0 : e }`, but well…

Thanks!

Comment: Since I cannot get any false values, the `map` option seems to be adequate. And yes, the messy one is really messy. :)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no built-in function to replace `nil` in an array, so yes, `map` is the way to go. If a shorter version would make you happier, you could do:

```
array.map {|e| e ? e : 0}
```

Answer (score 13):

To change the array after assignment:

```
array.map! { |x| x || 0 }
```

Note that this also converts `false` to `0`.

If you want to use zeros *during* assignment, it's a little messy:

```
i = 10
a = [1, 2, 3]
a += ([0] * (i - a.size)) << 2
# => [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

nil.to_i is 0, if all the numbers are integers then below should work. I think It is also the shortest answer here.

```
array.map!(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the array in place

```
array.map!{|x|x ?x:0}
```

If the array can contain `false` you'll need to use this instead

```
array.map!{|x|x.nil? ? 0:x}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a.select { |i| i }
```

This answer is too short so I am adding a few more words.

Comment: You can use a.compact for this feature what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to define your own function for adding a value to the array.

```
class Array
  def addpad(index,newval)
    concat(Array.new(index-size,0)) if index > size
    self[index] = newval
  end
end

a = [1,2,3]
a.addpad(10,2)
a => [1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2]
```